Does free multiplicative convolution become free additive convolution under logarithm?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $n\times n$ random matrices that have zero measure over degenerate matrices. For a positive definite matrix with eigen-decomposition $A = U \Lambda U^\top$, let $\log(A) = U \log(\Lambda) U^\top$, where $\log(\Lambda) = \text{diag}(\log(\lambda_1), \dots, \log(\lambda_n))$.

Assuming $X X^\top$ and $Y Y^\top$ are freely independent, is the limiting eigen-spectrum of $\log((XY)(XY)^\top)$ equal to the free additive convolution of $\log(X X^\top)$ and $\log(Y Y^\top)$?

On an intuitive level, this means that taking the logarithm converts multiplication to addition in freely independent matrices. I simulated this for various distributions of random $X$ and $Y$, and the empirical results confirm the hypothesis. Here is an example:

caption: Blue: $\log((XY)(XY)^\top)$, Red: free additive convolution of $\log(X X^\top)$ and $\log(Y Y^\top)$, when $X$ is a Gaussian and $Y$ is the inverse of a Gaussian matrix.
Is this hypothesis generally true?

I'm not sure the empirical results confirm your hypothesis. The fluctuations of your data don't seem overly large, and you may be seeing a real signal of the blue distribution being broader than the red one. This would also accord with the term I consider in my answer, which suggests that the blue distribution should be broader (although that term is only one partial contribution).

Your hypothesis seems unnatural for noncommuting variables - for noncommuting variables, shouldn't we expect Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff type corrections to exponentiations and logarithms ...

No, this is not true. Let's cast the question as follows: Is the eigenvalue distribution of $\log [ (1+\epsilon A)(1+\epsilon B)]$ the same as the one of $\log (1+\epsilon A) + \log (1+\epsilon B)$, where $A,B$ are Hermitean? (This is obtained by considering $X=X^T$, $Y=Y^T$ and defining $X^2 = 1+\epsilon A$,
$Y^2 = 1+\epsilon B$). $\epsilon $ is a parameter in which we can expand.
Well, this goes wrong as early as the second moments of the distributions at order $\epsilon^{4} $. By expanding in $\epsilon $ and picking out order $\epsilon^{4} $, one has
$$
\left. \mbox{Tr } (\log [ (1+\epsilon A)(1+\epsilon B)])^2 \right|_{\epsilon^{4} } = \epsilon^{4} \mbox{Tr}  \left( \frac{11}{12} A^4 + \frac{11}{12} B^4 + \frac{2}{3} A^3 B + \frac{2}{3} A B^3 + \frac{2}{3} A^2 B^2 -\frac{1}{6} ABAB \right)
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\left. \mbox{Tr } (\log (1+\epsilon A) + \log (1+\epsilon B))^2 \right|_{\epsilon^{4} } = \epsilon^{4} \mbox{Tr}  \left( \frac{11}{12} A^4 + \frac{11}{12} B^4 + \frac{2}{3} A^3 B + \frac{2}{3} A B^3 + \frac{1}{2} A^2 B^2 \right)
$$
If $A$ and $B$ were commuting variables, these would coincide. However, since they are instead free random variables, the second moments differ (at order $\epsilon^{4} $) by
$$
\Delta = \epsilon^{4} \frac{1}{6} \mbox{Tr } (A^2 B^2 -ABAB) = \epsilon^{4} \frac{1}{6} \left( \mbox{Tr } (A^2 ) \mbox{Tr } (B^2 ) - (\mbox{Tr } A)^2 \mbox{Tr } (B^2 ) - \mbox{Tr } (A^2 ) (\mbox{Tr } B)^2 + (\mbox{Tr } A)^2 (\mbox{Tr } B)^2 \right)
$$

for free mean-zero matrices $A,B$, one has $\mathbb{E}(ABAB)=\mathbb{E}(A^2B^2)$, so the two expressions would agree.

@CarloBeenakker - no, that is not how free random variables behave. If $\mbox{Tr} A = \mbox{Tr} B =0$, then $\mbox{Tr} (ABAB) =0$. The last line in my answer precisely gives the difference in terms of the individual moments.
